# check if a value exists in an external file (java)

Tags: java, file, list

Is it possible (and wise) to check if a value exists in an external text file.

So if i have a file: bankcodes.txt that contains the next lines:

```
INGB
ABNA
...
```

Is it possible to check if a value is present in this file?

The reason is that these values can change and need to be easily changed whitout making a new jar file.

If there is another, wiser way of doing this i would like to hear it too.

Comment: At start up read in the text file and read all entries line by line into a Set. Then check if your value is present in this set.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/best-way-to-read-a-text-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716623/110933

Read contents of file line by line and check the value you get for "line" for the value you want:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
try {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();

    while (line != null) {
        sb.append(line);
        sb.append("\n");
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    String everything = sb.toString();
} finally {
    br.close();
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i had read the other article before creating this question. So this is a decent way to solve such things?

Comment: @user: that's the way I'd probably do it. If the file was in, say, CSV format then I'd look at using one of the libraries available such as Open CSVReader.

Answer (score 1):

Give example how i did it , while **File.txt** -> our text and **ourValue** it the one we searching

```
    String ourValue="value"
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File.txt"));
    String line = br.readLine();
            boolean exist = false;
            while (line != null&&!exist) {
                if (ourValue.equals(line)) {
                    exist = true;
                } else {
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
            }
    System.out.println("the value " +ourValue+" exist in the Text? "+ exist);
        }
```